# REST API partially working - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I'm trying to create a basic REST style API with PHP and I'm having a strange issue. When I visit one of my pages (viewinput.php) through the URL /rest/viewinput.php the page loads fine. When I try through /rest/viewinput I get a "page not found" error.

So, here's the code that determines the type of request and where to send it. This is found on my server.php page

```
//in server.php
public function serve() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $paths = explode('/', $this->paths($uri));
    array_shift($paths); // 
    $resource = array_shift($paths);

if ($resource == 'rest') {
        $page = array_shift($paths);
        if (empty($page)) {
            $this->handle_base($method);
    } else {
    $this->handle_page($method, $page);
        }

    }
    else {
        // We only handle resources under 'clients'
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    } 
}
```

Since it is a GET method with a determined page name, it will be passed to this function

```
//in server.php
private function handle_page($method, $page) {
    switch($method) {  

    case 'GET':
    if($page == "viewinput"){ //I have both viewinput.php and viewinput just to check both. Only viewinput.php works
       $this->display_info();
    }
     if($page == "viewinput.php"){
       $this->display_info();
    }

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
        header('Allow: GET, PUT, DELETE');
        break;
    }
}
```

From here it is then sent to

```
//in server.php
function display_info(){
$view = new ViewInputs(); 
$view->view();  //this function is on viewinput.php
}
```

So, when I visit /rest/viewinput.php the view function displays properly. When I visit /rest/viewinput I get a "broken link" error.

I followed a tutorial online for a REST server [Found Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/) and it works just fine.

The following is in my httpd.conf file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* rest/server.php
```

This is my viewinput.php file. I believe that it's working correctly (when page loads, the serve function on server.php should run.

```
<?
include_once 'server.php';
class ViewInputs{

  function view(){
      $sql = mysql_query("select * from entry");
      ?> 
      <table>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Text</th>
          <col width="200">
          <col width="150">
        <?
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>
            <tr><td><? echo $result['id']." "; ?></td><td><? echo $result['text']; ?></td></tr>
            <?
        }
        ?> </table> <?
    }
}
$server = new server();
$server->serve(); 
?>
```

From httpd.conf. I may be wrong, but I believe this is how to allow a .htaccess file

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/rest"

<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride ALL
   Order deny, allow
   Deny from none
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
Require all ALLOW
</Files>
```

Comment: Your rewriterule transfers every request to `rest/server.php`, but your script is `/rest/viewinput.php`?

Comment: Should I just set it to rest/ then? I'm still new to this and it was on the tutorial. I figured it had something to do with the main file location.

Comment: Well no, you need the rewrite, but the idea is that every URL (/path/to/your/page) doesn't make the webserver go looking for that actual path, but gets handled by one script (your rest/server.php in this case) that uses that path as input to do its work.

Comment: No from what I read you don't actually have a viewinput.php file correct? It should be sent to server.php. What calls the serve() function? I believe the issue is with your rewrite though. I'm no rewrite expert but you have ^/.* which means it is looking for something with a .(period) in it /rest/viewinput does not have a period in it.

Comment: sorry, it is on viewinput.php. I made a comment in the code above

Comment: @Konerak That's exactly what I'm confused about. Shouldn't server.php handle the request? It handles the /rest/viewinput.php URL just fine, but not /rest/viewinput. As you can see, it should respond the same regardless if the .php is there. Is this an apache setting I need to change?

Comment: Are you sure server.php is handling the request, and not viewinput.php? With that rewriterule active, every request should go to server.php - so both viewinput.php and viewinput should work...

Comment: @Konerak I'm sure server.php is handling the request. I updated my post above to include viewinput.php. When I remove $server->serve() from viewinput.php the page no longer displays anything. I'm positive it's retrieving info from server.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is not written correctly. What is happening is that when you go to rest/viewinput.php that file actually exists so it is able to run. When you go to rest/viewinput that file doesn't exist. You can check your rewrite rule by going to http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ you will see your rewrite rule is no good.

The point of doing this is so that you don't have a veiwinput.php file, everything should be sent directly to the server.php file. Most likely the rewrite rule you want is something like this:

```
RewriteRule rest/* rest/server.php
```

If you want to actually go to viewinput.php there is no point in having a rewrite rule at all, just get rid of it.

If you want rest/viewinput to be treated as rest/viewinput.php then use this:

```
RewriteRule ^rest/([a-z]+) rest/$1.php
```

Comment: The point of doing a rewrite like you had is so that all requests get sent to a single file like server.php it can then include viewinput.php if needed. This is frameworks normally work like CakePHP, CI, Yii, etc... and most CMS's like wordpress, joomla, and drupal.

Comment: I changed the RewriteRule and instead of placing it in the http.conf file, I created a .htaccess file. I'm still getting an error, but its now a 404. Prior, I was just getting "link appears to be broken"

Comment: What rewrite rule did you change it to? Is your web server (assuming apache) setup to allow .htaccess?

Comment: I'm using the second rule. I want to be able to use /rest/viewinput to access the page as if it was /rest/viewinput.php. I'll update my post above to show the directory access (I think that's what its called)

Comment: Is the 404 error coming from your code? You have some if tests that if not true return a 404 header. Try commenting out this line "header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');" and see if you still get the 404 error.

Comment: Commented out the only 404's and I'm still getting the error. All of my files are located in C:\xampp\htdocs\rest including the .htaccess ,which I think I called out correctly in the httpd.conf file as shown above. Prior to the .htaccess file I didn't get a 404, just "link appears to be broken." I'm not sure if that means anything to you.